# SSL: Assessment failed: Unable to connect to the server (Apache2, Ubuntu)

Tags: apache-http-server, ssl, ubuntu-20.04

I am new here. I have been trying to install an SSL certificate on Ubuntu 20.04 with Apache2. The certificate an a positive SSL from Sectigo/Comodo.
When testing on SSLllabs, I get Assessment failed: Unable to connect to the server. Immuniweb shows "The HTTPS port (443) is closed, but the HTTP port (80) is open. Data exchange with the remote web server can be intercepted."

$ apache2ctl configtest yields "Syntax OK".
$ service apache2 restart yields: "Job for apache2.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status apache2.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details." This message disappears after $ sudo a2dissite.
I opened the firewall to ports 80 & 443. My config file:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
# The ServerName directive (...)

ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
DocumentRoot /var/www/ps-photo.net/html
ServerName ps-photo.net
ServerAlias www.ps-photo.net    
SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/private/ps-photo_net.key
SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/ps-photo_net.crt
SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/apache2/ssl/ssl-bundle.crt


# Available loglevels: (...)

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

# For most configuration files from conf-available/ (...)
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName ps-photo.net
  ServerAlias www.ps-photo.net
  Redirect permanent / https:///
   </VirtualHost>
```

$ netstat -anutp | grep :443 results in:

```
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
tcp        0      0 192.168.86.47:52130     216.58.211.2:443        TIME_WAIT   -                   
tcp        0      0 192.168.86.47:52098     216.58.211.2:443        ESTABLISHED 3314/firefox        
tcp        0      0 192.168.86.47:44654     143.204.55.34:443       TIME_WAIT   -                   
tcp        0      0 192.168.86.47:36284     91.228.74.198:443       TIME_WAIT   -                   
tcp        0      0 192.168.86.47:52104     216.58.211.2:443        ESTABLISHED 3314/firefox        
tcp        0      0 192.168.86.47:56528     143.204.55.115:443      ESTABLISHED 3314/firefox        
tcp        0      0 192.168.86.47:48606     192.0.73.2:443          ESTABLISHED 3314/firefox
```

Any hints would be appreciated. I am totally new to this.

Best,
Peter

Comment: is your server on a public IP or on your home network behind a NAT? if SSLlabs says that your port 443 is closed then it did not reach your server anyways and has nothing to do with your config. can you check that apache is listening? `netstat -anutp | grep :443` you need to get an entry with listen, if you could edit your post with the result.

Comment: I posted the results in my question. 
How do I determine if the server in on public IP or home network?

Comment: your server is not listening on 443, you need to check why it does not start, as your post says to check the journal, also check apache logs for errors...

Comment: I tried it all over with MacOS and Apache, same result. 
I will have to consult with the website provider, I think.

Comment: comment out the SSL directives and see if your site will work on port 80, if it comes up, then you will need to troubleshoot the SSL config. without checking the logs it is hard to guess what is wrong....